# springboot + JDBTemplate (No datasource specified error even though specified in application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=
```

i placed this `application.properties` in resources folder.

Java Class

```
@Component
public class data{

      @Autowired
      private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

      public void queryData(){
          String sql = "select * from DEPOSIT";
          jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
          jdbcTemplate.execute(sql);
      }

}
```

I am getting

> java.lang.Illegal Argument Exception:No Data Source Specified

I am getting this error message even though i specified data source in `application.properties`

I am using `Spring Boot` for this task. I Have added almost all the dependencies required in `POM`.

Not sure why i am not able to access data source. basically trying to access data from DB using `Spring boot`, `MySQL`, `jdbcTemplate`.
Not sure whats wrong here.
Do i have to add anything in the code so that data source can be specified in java class?

Comment: Remove `jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();` and put your DB values into application.properties, f.e. `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbName` , `spring.datasource.username=root` , `spring.datasource.password=root`. You can skip `spring.datasource.driver-class-name`, it will be guessed by spring from the `url` property. Make sure DB is running on the machine where you try to start your app. You can use the following link as a reference: https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/

Answer (score 0):

Add below properties to your application.properties file. This specifies the data source for your application. Do check if mysql is running on your machine before starting your application.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
spring.datasource.username=yourusername
spring.datasource.password=yourpassword
```

For additional information refer to below link:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html